# Misunderstanding of SUMO document

Tags: python, sumo

I want to know what this paragraph from the SUMO document exactly says:

> duaIterate.py supports many of the same options as sumo.
> Any options not listed when calling `duaIterate.py --help` can be passed to sumo by adding `sumo--long-option-name` arg after the regular options (i.e. `sumo--step-length 0.5`)

Answer (score 1):

`duaIterate.py` appears to be some sort of wrapper around SUMO. `duaIterate.py` has a number of arguments it accepts, and you can see them with `duaIterate.py --help`. `duaIterate.py` internally calls SUMO at some point. SUMO has its own set of arguments it accepts. Those are not explicitly listed in `duaIterate.py --help`. But you can pass arguments through to SUMO—if you know what arguments SUMO accepts and you know which ones you want to pass—by passing them with the prefix `sumo`, like `duaIterate.py sumo--step-length 0.5` for SUMO's `--step-length` argument. `duaIterate.py` will then include them when it calls SUMO internally.

Comment: Thank you deceze a lot.

Comment: Dear Deceze, I did what you said as following : duaiterate.py -n osm.net.xml -t od2trips.xml duarouter--additional-files add_file.xml duarouter--vtype-output output.xml --additional add_file.xml --max-convergence-deviation 0.05 --last-step 70 sumo--step-length 0.5....but, this error is displayed : "duaIterate.py: error: unrecognized arguments: sumo--step-length 0.5". What do you think of that? thank you in advance.

Comment: No idea, I'm just interpreting that help text to what seems reasonable, I don't have any actual knowledge of those specific tools.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of you.

Comment: You cannot mix the "regular" and the pass-through options. All pass-through options need to come at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by " All pass-through options need to come at the end"?  You mean "python ~>duaiterate.py sumo--step-length 0.5" separately?